# How do I create a responsive form using flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple inline form.

```
<form>
 <span>Signup to our list!</span>
 <input type="email" placeholder="your email address">
 <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

I want to use flexbox to evenly space out the elements. And then when the screen size gets too small, to wrap the elements onto their own rows, centered.

I've made a start here: http://codepen.io/magician11/pen/PPvVRv

Right now the issues are:

- they don't wrap onto their own lines,
- there is no spacing between the elements,
- I'm not sure how to center the elements when they wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code in your demo...

```
input[type="email"] {
  flex: 2 0 18rem;
}
```

... tells the `input` element to stretch the full available width of the container. So when that happens, there's no space left on the line, and your three items are lined up together with no space in between.

There are several ways to alter this behavior to create space between the elements. One easy way is to remove the `flex-grow: 2` factor from the code above. Try this:

```
input[type="email"] {
  flex: 0 1 60rem; /* don't grow, shrink proportionally, start at 60rem width */
}
```

For the items to wrap you need to allow the container to grow in height so it can accommodate the new rows of items:

```
form {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 30px; /* new; value for demo purposes only */
}
```

To center the items on wrap you can use a media query:

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 1000px ) {
  form { justify-content: center; }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpoaZq)

---

**Update** (based on comments)

> When it wraps, how do I create vertical space between the elements?

One simple way is to apply `margin` between flex items.

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 1000px ) {
     form { justify-content: center; }
     form > * { margin-bottom: 15px; }
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvVEQE)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution http://codepen.io/gmrash/pen/KdLOZJ

```
<form>
  <span>Signup to our list!</span>
  <input type="email" placeholder="your email address">
  <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
```

---

```
form {
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: orange;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

span {
  flex: 0 0 8rem;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

input[type="email"] {
  flex: 2 1 18rem;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  flex: 0 0 8rem;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this working for you? [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gioele/95d1fjpz/3/)
Just deleted `flex-shrink`and `flex-grow` to inputs.